# Cannot properly use Gigabit LAN, firewall & switch, home network

Tags: networking, firewall, lan

I have a netgear prosafe 8 port vpn gigabit firewall and a netgear prosafe gigbit 8 port switch on my home LAN plus a UBEE cable modem. The connectivity of these devices are as follows... UBEE>FIREWALL>SWITCH

I have some devices connected to the firewall and others from the switch. I should metino that the UBEE has switching capabilities also. My problem is two fold. First, i need 1gb/sec speeds beginning from the firewall, through the switch, to every device that supports it. The indicators on the firewall will indicate what ports are running at 1gb/s speeds along with the GUI config. Devices connected along the way will show 1gb/s connections on their network interfaces but i have no way to accurately test this yet.

Second, i have a 30mbit/s connection coming in. Running speedtest.net and the speedtest from my ISP when i am directly plugged into the modem gives me results in accordance with what i am paying for. When i connect to any of my other devices, either the firewall or switch, i get half of the throughput.

I have looked in the firewall and switch confiiguration menus and cannot find anything that would be limiting my speeds. The lights on both my firewall and switch are showing 1gb/s connections whic leads me to believe my cat5 lines are ok, but i have not extensively tested them to make sure otherwise.

Does anyone have tips for me to realize the potential of my network? Thanks for the help

VR,
E

Comment: If you include information about the OS you are running, people will be able to suggest tools for troubleshooting your lan.

Comment: Are you using Cat 5, or Cat5e? I thought Cat 5e and not Cat 5 supported 1000 Mbps?

Comment: I have cat5 cables for the time being and i realize that i need to go with cat5e or cat6 for gigabit speeds.

One problem though, when i connect my computer with a cat6 cable directly to the cable modem, I get the expected speeds. When I unplug from the modem and connect to the firewall using the same cable my speed is cut in half. Logically this leads to a firewall conf setting but i cant, for the life of me, figure out what it could be. Or perhaps there is another problem?

vr, Erik